# Assign scalar value to all elements of numpy array which are in another array

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a numpy array `a = np.arange(10)`, and I need to assign the values in `ignore = [2,3,4]` to be number `255`, like this:

```
a = np.arange(10)
ignore_value = [3,4,5]
a[a in ignore_value] = 255 # what is the correct way to implement this?
```

The last line in the program above cannot be accepted by Python3.5 but it shows what I want to do.

Edit:

I found a solution, but it's not vectorized.

```
for el in ignore_value:
    a[a == el] = 255
```

This looks really ugly and is very slow since there is a `for` loop here, so do I have a better way ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to select elements by value, not by index?  The desired result is `[0,1,2,255,255,255,6,7,8,9]`?

Comment: Yes, by value, not index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [500]: a = np.arange(10)
In [501]: ignore_value = [3,4,5]
In [502]: np.isin(a, ignore_value)
Out[502]: 
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
In [503]: a[np.isin(a, ignore_value)]=255
In [504]: a
Out[504]: array([  0,   1,   2, 255, 255, 255,   6,   7,   8,   9])
```

You could also construct the mask with:

```
In [506]: a[:,None]==ignore_value
Out[506]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
In [507]: (a[:,None]==ignore_value).any(axis=1)
Out[507]: 
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) with boolean indexing.

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> ignore_value = [3,4,5]
>>> a[np.isin(a, ignore_value)] = 255
>>> a
array([  0,   1,   2, 255, 255, 255,   6,   7,   8,   9])
```

... or with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a = np.where(np.isin(a, ignore_value), 255, a)
>>> a
array([  0,   1,   2, 255, 255, 255,   6,   7,   8,   9])
```

In both cases, `np.isin(a, ignore_value)` will give you a boolean array indicating where `a` has a value occuring in `ignore_value`.

```
>>> np.isin(a, ignore_value)
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False])
```